# Detecting active use of camera

Tags: ios, camera

I need to detect whenever another app is using the iPhone's/iPad's camera while my app is running. My app keeps on running in background (audio), but it does not use the camera itself. I just need to find out if another app is using any camera at all.

Moreover, I want to use as little CPU resources as possible to minimize battery usage.

I've tried without success:

- running a simple `AVCaptureSession` to catch interruption notifications (it's never notified)
- call `lockForConfiguration` on all `AVCaptureDevice`s
- periodically monitor the `enabled` property of `AVCaptureInputPort` (it's always YES)
- periodically monitor the `connected` property of `AVCaptureDevice` (it's always YES)

For clarification:

- I do not need a way to detect existence of camera(s)
- I do not need a way to find out if the camera is active in my app

Thanks for any pointers.

EDIT: this a security feature: I want to warn the user if there's a slight possibility that a malicious (foreground) app is taking a photo or video of the user or the surroundings while my app is in active (background) use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iOS documentation doesn't say anything about a way your app can be notified when another app runs the camera. That doesn't sound like something Apple would ever allow either. Besides, it wouldn't do any good to know if another app is running the camera because: a) your app cannot use the camera if it's not active, and b) your app cannot affect the operation of another app in any way. Try to think of an alternative to what you're trying to achieve, because unfortunately, this way is impossible.

Comment: thanks a lot. Note that you do get such notifications for the iOS audio device. And I don't necessarily need a notification, it's OK for me to poll every X seconds. So a method "isCameraActive" would be enough. And believe me, merely knowing /will/ do any good to my app.

Comment: Even with polling, I don't think it's possible. Can you explain why you need to know if the camera is active? Maybe there is a workaround.

Comment: I've added some info for my motivation for this feature

Comment: You cannot implement such a security feature. It's Apple's job to make sure malicious apps are not sold on the app store, and it's the job of iOS to make sure the camera cannot not be used by a background app. Since iOS will not allow an app to run the camera in the background, you don't have to worry about checking for it.

Comment: @Florian - The reason you see provisions for being notified when audio is playing is that applications in the background can also play audio. No background applications can or will be able to capture from the camera, given the potential privacy implications of that, so you're not going to have a notification for this. I'm afraid that what you're trying to do won't be something you can realize on a non-jailbroken device.

Comment: Florian, since Brad has confirmed my answer, can you accept it to close the question?

Comment: I read your answers, but it's not 100% like that. When my app is active in background doing audio, I don't want any foreground app take photos or video. If they do nonetheless, I'd like to know it. For the user's privacy. And I don't see the privacy infringement when I can query if another app is using a camera. So I wait a bit more to see if anyone has found a trick.

Comment: @Florian, did you find a way to see if another application is using the camera?

Comment: @WilliamGrand no I haven't. We ended up blocking the camera by actively using it... not  nice, but the best we could do to prevent visual eavesdropping. I believe that we were able to use the camera in background because it was marked as a VoIP application. But I haven't looked into this for years, so it's possible that current iOS offers other possibilities.